# Data added in first event is not reflect in second event in flutter bloc

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I created a bloc with 2 events.I initialise a class in first event and called when click on a first button.In second event i added some datas to that class but when i call the second event it throws a null error.
First event

```
class MyBloc extends Bloc<MqttEvents,MqttState>{
MqttServerClient? _client;
MqttBloc() : super(MqttInitailState()){

    on<MqttConnectEvent> ((event, emit) async{
    
      
          _client=MqttServerClient.withPort('', '',);
          _client!.logging(on: true);
    
        
          } on Exception catch (e) {
            print('EXAMPLE::client exception - $e');
            _client!.disconnect();
            exit(-1);
          }
    
        });

Second event

    on<PublishEvent>((event,emit) async{
          
            final MqttClientPayloadBuilder builder = MqttClientPayloadBuilder();
            builder.addString(event.message.toString());
            _client!.publishMessage("flutter/test", MqttQos.exactlyOnce, builder.payload!);
        //this line is throwing an error.
        });
}}
```

How to access _client in PublishEvent?

Comment: Is _client a member of the Bloc?  Are you sure that when you add your second event to the bloc you are using the same instance of the bloc that you used to add the first event?  Maybe add a breakpoint or a print statement to the constructor of the bloc to make sure you are using the same instance.

Comment: I edited my sample code.Please  check now.

Comment: Please show the code where you are using MyBloc for both screens.  Such as a BlocProvider.